# Custom service not properly declared

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm new to Angular.js and am stuck when defining a custom service. I followed the tutorial at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial.

My app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myControllers',
  'myFilters',
]);
```

My services.js:

```
myApp.service('MathService', function() {

    this.add = function(a, b) { return a + b };

    this.subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b };

    this.multiply = function(a, b) { return a * b };

    this.divide = function(a, b) { return a / b };
});
```

My controllers.js:

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers.controller('catalogCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', MathService, '$http',
   function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    console.log(MathService.add(4,5));
   }
]);
```

Everything works fine until MathService.add(4,5) is called.

The error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MathService is not defined controllers.js:8(anonymous function)
```

I'm missing something and can't find what. Any help welcome! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to wrap `MathService` in single quotes and then put in the `function($scope, ... MathService ... ' as well.

```
myControllers.controller('catalogCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'MathService', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, MathService, $http) {

console.log(MathService.add(4,5));
```

}]);

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to pass `MathService` into your function, and you missed single quotes too.

```
myControllers.controller('catalogCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', `MathService`, '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams, MathService, $http) {
        console.log(MathService.add(4,5));
 }]);
```